# MySql SUM function combined with where conditional

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

This is the first part of a crazy query I have to put together so expect another question on here soon!

I have this table [image: Table Description]

What I am trying to do is to get a list of `CONTEXT` that have a `SUM(FILE_SIZE)` greater than 5 gigs.

I have every part of the query figured out except putting in the where clause.

```
SELECT CONTEXT,SUM(FILE_SIZE) AS size FROM CONTENT_RESOURCE GROUP BY CONTEXT.
```

What I'm having trouble putting together is something like:

```
WHERE SUM(FILE_SIZE) > 5000000000
```

This would be done for each unique CONTEXT.

So if there is data like this:

```
1 | A
4 | A
2 | C
6 | C
8 | B
```

The result would be something like:

```
5 | A
8 | C
8 | B
```

So I need to get the `SUM(FILE_SIZE)` for all of the different `CONTEXT`s and then only return the ones where it is greater than 5000000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `having` clause allows you to apply conditions on groups (and aggregate results) created by the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   context, SUM(file_size) AS size 
FROM     content_resource
GROUP BY context
HAVING   SUM(file_size) > 5000000000
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't run the query yet as it takes 10-20 minutes to complete but I tested it on a smaller data set and it looked like it worked. Expect a few more SQL questions today too!